# How do we know that Bitcoin supply is actually capped at 21 million?

Tags: cryptography, money-supply, satoshi-nakamoto, shrinking-money-supply, supply

Everyone says that the Bitcoin supply is capped at 21 million. But how did everybody come to this number? In Nakamoto's paper, I could not find this number. Can someone explain where it is or how we can infer this maximum based on Nakamoto's paper? I'm not a mathematician. Maybe, it's clear for everybody but to me this seems to be a fantasy number.

```
Nakamoto, S. (2008). Bitcoin: A peer-to-peer electronic cash system. Decentralized
Business Review, page 21260.
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the bitcoin 21 million cap implemented?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2756/how-is-the-bitcoin-21-million-cap-implemented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitepaper doesn't mention any specific supply cap, and actually the distribution parameters it suggests are very different from the actual parameters implemented in Bitcoin:

> #### 6. Incentive
>
> By convention, the first transaction in a block is a special transaction that starts a new coin owned by the creator of the
> block. This adds an incentive for nodes to support the network, and
> provides a way to initially distribute coins into circulation, since
> there is no central authority to issue them. The steady addition of a
> constant of amount of new coins is analogous to gold miners expending
> resources to add gold to circulation. [...] Once a
> predetermined number of coins have entered circulation, the incentive
> can transition entirely to transaction fees and be completely
> inflation free.

I would interpret the words "steady addition of a constant of amount of new coins" as a constant mining subsidy that abruptly ends after a predetermined amount has been mined.

The announcement of the release of the first Bitcoin client by Nakamoto mentions the supply cap and parameters as we know them today:
https://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2009-January/014994.html

> Total circulation will be 21,000,000 coins.  It'll be distributed to
> network nodes when they make blocks, with the amount cut in half every
> 4 years.
>
> first 4 years: 10,500,000 coins
> next 4 years: 5,250,000 coins
> next 4 years: 2,625,000 coins
> next 4 years: 1,312,500 coins etc...

And of course, you can look into the source code of Bitcoin Core or any other Bitcoin node software to verify the supply cap for yourself. See [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/110161/121614).